# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5.3"

Tags: java, android, exception, numberformatexception

when running this code i am getting this java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5.3" Exception. how can we resolve this type of exception.any other way we can handle this without try and catch? value can be any thing.it's not fixed that it will always be float.it can be integer and double too.is there any way we can handle all three no matter what comes .without using try catch.

passing this in line 79 PreferenceConstants.DEVICE_LAST_ERROR_CODE

```
 public static final String DEVICE_LAST_ERROR_CODE = "device_last_error_code";
```

please find the code below.

```
package com.pds.ftp.view.activity;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.pds.ftp.R;
import com.pds.ftp.app.FTPApp;
import com.pds.ftp.constant.UIConstant;
import com.pds.ftp.infrastructure.ReaderUsbInterf;
import com.pds.ftp.middleware.FTPPrivilegedServiceProvider;
import com.pds.ftp.middleware.PollingLooperThread;
import com.pds.ftp.middleware.ShutDownManager;
import com.pds.ftp.model.dbsync.DBSynchronizationPool;
import com.pds.ftp.transaction.shutdown.EntryExitCheck;
import com.pds.ftp.transaction.shutdown.ShutdownStateCache;
import com.pds.ftp.utils.Util;
import com.pds.hardwareadapter.ingenicoreader.IngenicoReaderDirect;
import com.pds.infrastructure.constants.PreferenceConstants;
import com.pds.infrastructure.interfaces.ILogOperation;
import com.pds.infrastructure.logger.LogCriticalEvent;
import com.pds.infrastructure.logger.LogInfoEvent;
import com.pds.infrastructure.logger.LogWarningEvent;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class PowerOffActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public static final String TYPE = "action_type";
    public static final int TYPE_SHUTDOWN = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_RESTART = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_END_OF_BUSINESS_HOURS = 2;
    public static final int SHUTDOWN_DELAY = 1000 * 30;
    public static final int SHUTDOWN_WAIT = 1000;
    public static final int READER_REBOOT = 3;

    @Inject
    ILogOperation logOperation;

    @Inject
    EntryExitCheck entryExitCheck;

    @Inject
    ShutdownStateCache shutdownStateCache;

    @Inject
    IngenicoReaderDirect ingenicoReaderDirect;

    @Inject
    PollingLooperThread pollingLooperThread;

    @Inject
    ReaderUsbInterf usbInterf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        isShutDownRequestInitiated = true;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_power_off);

        shutdownStateCache.setShutdownState(true); //Shutdown state is true as power is disconnected
        logOperation.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "PowerOff Screen Started");

    }

    boolean keepOnRunning = true;

    private void checkForPendingTaskBeforeShutdown() {
        keepOnRunning = true;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pollingLooperThread.onpause();
                if (getIntent() != null) {
                    int type = getIntent().getIntExtra(TYPE, 0);
                    int currentErrorCode = Integer.parseInt(configParams.getString(PreferenceConstants.DEVICE_LAST_ERROR_CODE));
                    int restartCount = configParams.getInt(PreferenceConstants.PREF_FTP_RESTART_COUNT);
                    if (type == TYPE_END_OF_BUSINESS_HOURS || (currentErrorCode == LogCriticalEvent.CARD_READER_MALFUNCTION && restartCount == 1)) {
                        logOperation.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "Calling reader reset command due to EOB or CARD_READER_MALFUNCTION. currentErrorCode:: "+currentErrorCode);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3500);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logOperation.logVerbose(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, e,"Exception caused in Thread.sleep during reset reader");
                        }
                        ingenicoReaderDirect.resetReader();
                    }
                } else{
                    logOperation.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "getIntent() is null");
                }

                while (keepOnRunning) {

                    if (entryExitCheck.getShutDownDBTaskCounter() == 0) {
                        logOperation.logVerbose(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "All threads are completed");
                        keepOnRunning = false;
                    } else {
                        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) >= SHUTDOWN_DELAY) {
                            logOperation.logVerbose(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "Time exceeds 30 sec,initiating shutdown");
                            keepOnRunning = false;
                        } else {
                            logOperation.logVerbose(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "Threads still running");
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(SHUTDOWN_WAIT);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logOperation.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO,e,"checkForPendingTaskBeforeShutdown Exception");
                    }
                }

                performShutdownProcess();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkForPendingTaskBeforeShutdown();
    }

    private void performShutdownProcess() {
        if (!Util.shutdown_file_available()) {
            FTPApp.isShuttingDownState = true;
            Util.setLastShutDownDateTime(configParams);
            if (getIntent() != null) {
                int type = getIntent().getIntExtra(TYPE, 0);
                String state = getIntent().getStringExtra(UIConstant.UISTATE);

                if (type == TYPE_END_OF_BUSINESS_HOURS) {
                    logOperation.logWarning(LogWarningEvent.DEVICE_SCHEDULED_OUT_OF_SERVICE, 2, "Device restarting because of end of business hours");
                }

                /*if (state.contains(UIConstant.IGNITION_OFF)) {
                    FTPApp.isShuttingDownState = true;
                }*/

                if (type == TYPE_RESTART || type == TYPE_END_OF_BUSINESS_HOURS|| type == READER_REBOOT) {
                    logOperation.logWarning(LogWarningEvent.DEVICE_REBOOTED, "Device is RESTARTING.. Coming from:- " + state);
                } else {
                    logOperation.logWarning(LogWarningEvent.DEVICE_SHUT_DOWN, "Device is shutting down Reason:- IGNITION... Coming From:- " + state);
                }
            } else {
                logOperation.logWarning(LogWarningEvent.DEVICE_REBOOTED, "Device is RESTARTING. Reason:- OTHER");
            }
            usbInterf.close();
            ShutDownManager.getInstance().shutDownDevice();
        }
    }

    @Override
    void prepareTextToSpeechAndSpeak() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }
}
```

getting this in logs it looks like this exception is coming from line 79

```
4,0,05.16.2022_09.09.00.822,java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5.3"
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
com.pds.ftp.view.activity.PowerOffActivity$1.run(PowerOffActivity.java:79)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Line 8922: 2,1000,05.16.2022_09.09.00.910,Info,Current Error Code = 0
```

Comment: The reason is because “5.3” isn’t an integer. You can handle it like any other Java exception.

Comment: ok, how can i handle this can you answer this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any other way we can handle this without try and catch?

You need to parse it with the right parse method so that the exception is not thrown.

> value can be any thing.

Well if that is *literally* true, it means that you cannot parse it, except the most trivial sense.

> it's not fixed that it will always be float.it can be integer and double too.

Ah  ... so when you said "any thing" you didn't mean anything?

There are three possible ways to handle this:

1. Just read the error code as a string, and don't attempt to parse it.

   Ask yourself: do you actually *need* to treat the error code as a number?  What does that buy you?  And what if the error code isn't a recognizable number at all?  (Will your application be able to cope?)
2. Parse the error code using `parseDouble`, and represent it as a `double`. The syntax parsed by `parseDouble` is the same as for `parseFloat` and a superset of what is accepted by `parseInt`.  Specifically, `parseDouble` will happily parse an integer value ... and give you the `double` representation of that integer.

   The downside is that for large enough integers, the `double` representation will be imprecise / inaccurate.  Depending on the actual code values, this might cause problems.
3. If you must parse it with the right type then the way you avoid try / catch would be to use `Pattern` to implement regexes to test which of the expected formats the error code is in.  Then call the corresponding `parseXXX` method to parse it.

   The downside is that you now need three (or more) different variables with types `int`, `float`, `double` and so on to represent the parsed error code values.  And all of the places where you used the error code later in your application will have to deal with that.
4. And of course, you could just use a sequence try-catches.

Comment: What if i go by your second suggestion? i am new to Java. Can you help me implement this? I just need to add double.parsedouble?

Comment: Isn't it obvious?  Change the line that calls `Integer.parseInt` to call `Double.parseDouble` instead.  Assign it to a `double` instead of an `int`.  Then adjust the code that uses the code ...

Comment: Note: if you don't try to do these things for your self, you will always be "new at Java".  StackOverflow is neither a teaching site or a site to go to get people to do your coding for you for free.  Show some initiative please.

Comment: Stephen, thank you for your suggestion. I will try to do it myself

Answer (score 3):

The line in question is

```java
int currentErrorCode = Integer.parseInt(configParams.getString(PreferenceConstants.DEVICE_LAST_ERROR_CODE));
```

this parses an integer, not a float; it expects a string representation of an integer. `5.3` is not an integer and contains a decimal point, causing the `NumberFormatException`. Use `Float.parseFloat` or `Double.parseDouble` instead; depending on your use case, you might want to round the result to an int.

Comment: any other way we can handle this without try and catch? value can be any thing.it's not fixed that it will always be float.it can be integer and double too.is there any way we can handle all three no matter what comes .without using try catch.

Comment: Use Double.parseDouble, that'll work for both integers and floats (which are a subset of what doubles can represent)